# Do all POSIX shells implement arithmetic expansion $((...)) in the same way?

Tags: posix, dash

I'm trying to write a shell script which should work under any POSIX shell, and I found what seems to be an odd quirk of `dash`. I'm wondering whether this is something I can rely on working under other POSIX compatible shells, or whether it is simply an unintentional feature of the `dash` shell.

In an arithmetic expansion a variable can be written either with or without the inital dollar sign (except in the case of the positional parameters, which must always be written with a dollar sign, `$1`, `$2` etc).

But I've found that the behaviour of `"$((X))"` is different from `"$(($X))"` in that `"$(($X))"` seems to be expanded *twice,* rather than just once. I.e. if my variable `X` contains the *name of another variable* (`X=Y`), which in turn contains a numeric value (`Y=1`) then `"$(($X))"` will return `1`, while `"$((X))"` will just produce an 'Illegal number: Y' error.

Can I rely on this behavior being the same in other POSIX shells?

### The odd behavior

`"$((X))"` and `"$(($X))"` do not behave the same.

```
$ X=Y; Y=1
$ echo "$((X))"
dash: 1: Illegal number: Y
$ echo "$(($X))"
1
```

### Expected behavior

Just for completeness I here include what with no indirection and two layers of indirection. With no indirection everyting works as expected:

```
$ X=1
$ echo "$((X))"
1
$ echo "$(($X))"
1
```

As expected, two layers of indirection does not work (though notice that the error messages are referring to different values).

```
$ X=Y; Y=Z; Z=1
$ echo "$((X))"
dash: 6: Illegal number: Y
$ echo "$(($X))"
dash: 7: Illegal number: Z
```

This question is somewhat related to this question about [Arithmetic expansion and parameter expansion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278670/arithmetic-expansion-and-parameter-expansion) but it’s not the same since that's dealing with the behaviour of `bash` and more advanced shells, but I'm wondering about expected POSIX behavior.

Comment: The above answer is attached to a bash-tagged question, but the principle is the same here — parameter expansion happens before arithmetic expansion.

Comment: See also [Bash: Arithmetic expansion, parameter expansion, and the comma operator](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/572125/86440) (again, purportedly bash-specific).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your question is POSIX-generic, and related questions appear to concern more advanced shells, I’ll answer this separately.

The behaviour you’re seeing comes from two different expansions, parameter expansion and arithmetic expansion, [which POSIX specifies in that order](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06). With

```
$ X=Y; Y=1
```

your first example only uses arithmetic expansion:

```
$ echo "$((X))"
```

tries to interpret `X`’s value as an arithmetic expression, and fails, because “Y” isn’t a number.

Your second example uses both:

```
$ echo "$(($X))"
```

is expanded (parameter expansion) to

```
$ echo "((Y))"
```

and arithmetic expansion then uses `Y`’s value, 1.

See also [Understand two examples using indirect expansion for variable expansion in arithmetic expressions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/382251/86440) and [Bash: Arithmetic expansion, parameter expansion, and the comma operator](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/572125/86440), among others.

Comment: Ah, so it comes down to the *order* of the different types of expansions! (But of course it does! I feel silly not to have thought of this before I asked my question.) I for some reason got it into my head that `$` expansion would be a thing, but the expansions of `$(...)`, `$((...))` and variables actually occur in different steps.

Comment: The first referene under "see also" is illgeal since neither `1+1` nor `b++` are integer constants but free text. If you use `$((var))`, then `var` needs to contain an integer number. A shell that allows this is questionable and a script that uses it is non-conforming.